# Render a table using renderers when content of cell overflows to next page

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7, renderer

I want to add a table on PDF. I am using itext7. This table which I am using has one cell and contains content which can grow up to many pages. And this is just an test case. There can be a table with multiple such cells. So, I need to render such tables using renderers. 
The approach I am using is below:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(25,25, 250, 380);

    PdfWriter writer =new PdfWriter(DEST);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A6);
    pdfDoc.addNewPage();
    int pageNum =1;
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Table table = new Table(2);

    table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Column1")));
    table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Column2")));

    String cellContent1="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam metus elit, ornare et justo nec, ornare dignissim leo. Praesent in egestas erat. Donec id nunc libero. Nullam aliquam sodales sollicitudin. Proin ac egestas nunc. Nunc et suscipit augue. Curabitur porta tempor nunc vel suscipit. Suspendisse imperdiet nunc id quam aliquet fermentum. Pellentesque ut dolor non odio congue blandit. Morbi laoreet magna quam, quis suscipit nunc pulvinar et. Nullam sit amet semper odio, sagittis dictum erat.\n"+

        "Curabitur sagittis arcu turpis, et tincidunt quam congue in. Nullam vitae felis id dui fringilla tincidunt. Nulla ullamcorper nisi non arcu fermentum, eu tempor lectus mattis. Aliquam leo purus, vulputate et ornare in, tincidunt sit amet mi. Sed sollicitudin et sapien vel hendrerit. Morbi id sodales sapien. In non nisl velit. Mauris maximus sodales lectus, ac dignissim elit cursus ac. Nulla viverra, velit sed cursus tincidunt, ex risus posuere diam, lobortis congue metus eros at lorem. Cras a ligula tortor. Vestibulum efficitur diam eros, eget dapibus magna cursus sed.\n"+
        "Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam ut velit pretium diam vestibulum consectetur. Praesent dignissim id sapien eget ultrices. Nam non libero iaculis dolor mattis egestas et quis leo. Sed vitae libero a enim viverra finibus sit amet sed nulla. Sed vitae sem hendrerit, posuere justo sagittis, placerat justo. Aenean felis nisi, tincidunt faucibus sem at, egestas interdum nibh. Curabitur venenatis neque nec volutpat mollis. Phasellus vel tellus ut nisl consequat gravida. Maecenas eget ligula vestibulum, finibus turpis a, hendrerit est. Cras eleifend mollis commodo.\n"+

        "Morbi quam velit, elementum nec turpis porttitor, venenatis sagittis nunc. Sed et nisi ipsum. Maecenas eget tellus in dui condimentum dictum a tempus sem. Maecenas consectetur nisl sit amet accumsan volutpat. Sed dictum massa vitae urna aliquam imperdiet. Nam at ex feugiat dolor vestibulum vehicula. Nullam leo magna, porta ac ex vitae, malesuada fermentum turpis. Donec vel turpis quis ligula feugiat molestie quis at nisi. Quisque efficitur velit odio, id rhoncus diam varius eu. Duis dui mi, scelerisque at faucibus ac, sodales sed est. Sed dictum aliquet semper.\n"+


        "Sed erat ipsum, vehicula nec magna sed, aliquam volutpat lorem. Integer et auctor nisl, at auctor lorem. Nam bibendum urna nec quam cursus, vitae rhoncus justo semper. Morbi posuere dapibus quam vel euismod. Morbi id maximus augue, ut vulputate turpis. Cras posuere auctor justo, in ultricies nunc tincidunt id. Sed luctus nisl lacus, in facilisis erat ultricies id. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi accumsan lectus nec dolor ultricies dignissim. Sed quis finibus lectus.\n"+

                "Pellentesque aliquet ex eget cursus accumsan. In ultrices tempus orci sed ultrices. Maecenas lectus nunc, consectetur ac suscipit et, tempus rutrum ipsum. Nulla accumsan tincidunt dignissim. Sed malesuada sapien elit, ac semper urna maximus at. Nunc eleifend tortor nec ligula auctor, sit amet sagittis turpis sagittis. Nam laoreet justo sed gravida iaculis. Fusce ornare quam quis arcu gravida rutrum. Aliquam vitae augue sit amet nisi finibus ullamcorper. Proin quis placerat velit. Integer malesuada erat nec massa tempus pretium.";

    Cell cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(cellContent1));
    table.addCell(cell);

    cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(cellContent1));
    table.addCell(cell);

    TableRenderer tableRenderer = (TableRenderer) table.createRendererSubTree();

    while ((tableRenderer = addTableToPage(pdfDoc, pageNum++, rectangle, tableRenderer, document)) != null) {
        pdfDoc.addNewPage();
    }
    document.close();

}

public TableRenderer addTableToPage(PdfDocument pdfDoc, int pageNum, Rectangle rectangle, TableRenderer renderer, Document document) {
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(pageNum);
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), page.getResources(), pdfDoc);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, rectangle);

    renderer.setParent(canvas.getRenderer());
    LayoutResult result = renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(pageNum, rectangle)));
    IRenderer rendererToAdd = result.getStatus() == LayoutResult.FULL ? renderer : result.getSplitRenderer();
    canvas.getRenderer().addChild(rendererToAdd.setParent(canvas.getRenderer()));

    return result.getStatus() != LayoutResult.FULL ? (TableRenderer ) result.getOverflowRenderer() : null;
}
```

This approach works for rendering a paragraph using ParagraphRenderer, but why it is not rendering table using tablerenderer?  I believe the selection of renderer is not correct.
Kindly suggest the correct approach for given problem and what is wrong in the above code?

Comment: I’m not familiar with itext7, but returning a `TableRenderer` from `addTableToPage` and doing nothing with it looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason of doing all the layouting yourself. You don't seem to have any custom drawing logic in your code except the custom rectangle area where you want to put your content. You can change document margins with `Document#setMargins(float, float, float, float)`, but I will show you an even more flexible approach. Just use the standard layouting mechanism without any manual work and use `ColumnDocumentRenderer` to define a column where your content will be placed:

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DEST);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A6);
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(25,25, 250, 380);
ColumnDocumentRenderer documentRenderer = new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, new Rectangle[] {rectangle});
document.setRenderer(documentRenderer);

Table table = new Table(2);

table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Column1")));
table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Column2")));

String cellContent1="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam metus elit, ornare et justo nec, ornare dignissim leo. Praesent in egestas erat. Donec id nunc libero. Nullam aliquam sodales sollicitudin. Proin ac egestas nunc. Nunc et suscipit augue. Curabitur porta tempor nunc vel suscipit. Suspendisse imperdiet nunc id quam aliquet fermentum. Pellentesque ut dolor non odio congue blandit. Morbi laoreet magna quam, quis suscipit nunc pulvinar et. Nullam sit amet semper odio, sagittis dictum erat.\n"+

        "Curabitur sagittis arcu turpis, et tincidunt quam congue in. Nullam vitae felis id dui fringilla tincidunt. Nulla ullamcorper nisi non arcu fermentum, eu tempor lectus mattis. Aliquam leo purus, vulputate et ornare in, tincidunt sit amet mi. Sed sollicitudin et sapien vel hendrerit. Morbi id sodales sapien. In non nisl velit. Mauris maximus sodales lectus, ac dignissim elit cursus ac. Nulla viverra, velit sed cursus tincidunt, ex risus posuere diam, lobortis congue metus eros at lorem. Cras a ligula tortor. Vestibulum efficitur diam eros, eget dapibus magna cursus sed.\n"+
        "Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam ut velit pretium diam vestibulum consectetur. Praesent dignissim id sapien eget ultrices. Nam non libero iaculis dolor mattis egestas et quis leo. Sed vitae libero a enim viverra finibus sit amet sed nulla. Sed vitae sem hendrerit, posuere justo sagittis, placerat justo. Aenean felis nisi, tincidunt faucibus sem at, egestas interdum nibh. Curabitur venenatis neque nec volutpat mollis. Phasellus vel tellus ut nisl consequat gravida. Maecenas eget ligula vestibulum, finibus turpis a, hendrerit est. Cras eleifend mollis commodo.\n"+

        "Morbi quam velit, elementum nec turpis porttitor, venenatis sagittis nunc. Sed et nisi ipsum. Maecenas eget tellus in dui condimentum dictum a tempus sem. Maecenas consectetur nisl sit amet accumsan volutpat. Sed dictum massa vitae urna aliquam imperdiet. Nam at ex feugiat dolor vestibulum vehicula. Nullam leo magna, porta ac ex vitae, malesuada fermentum turpis. Donec vel turpis quis ligula feugiat molestie quis at nisi. Quisque efficitur velit odio, id rhoncus diam varius eu. Duis dui mi, scelerisque at faucibus ac, sodales sed est. Sed dictum aliquet semper.\n"+


        "Sed erat ipsum, vehicula nec magna sed, aliquam volutpat lorem. Integer et auctor nisl, at auctor lorem. Nam bibendum urna nec quam cursus, vitae rhoncus justo semper. Morbi posuere dapibus quam vel euismod. Morbi id maximus augue, ut vulputate turpis. Cras posuere auctor justo, in ultricies nunc tincidunt id. Sed luctus nisl lacus, in facilisis erat ultricies id. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi accumsan lectus nec dolor ultricies dignissim. Sed quis finibus lectus.\n"+

        "Pellentesque aliquet ex eget cursus accumsan. In ultrices tempus orci sed ultrices. Maecenas lectus nunc, consectetur ac suscipit et, tempus rutrum ipsum. Nulla accumsan tincidunt dignissim. Sed malesuada sapien elit, ac semper urna maximus at. Nunc eleifend tortor nec ligula auctor, sit amet sagittis turpis sagittis. Nam laoreet justo sed gravida iaculis. Fusce ornare quam quis arcu gravida rutrum. Aliquam vitae augue sit amet nisi finibus ullamcorper. Proin quis placerat velit. Integer malesuada erat nec massa tempus pretium.";

Cell cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(cellContent1));
table.addCell(cell);

cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(cellContent1));
table.addCell(cell);

document.add(table);

document.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, it worked fine. Now, there can be parallel tables starting from different height on each page addition. Also, i need to call addNewPage() explicitly as there are certain other calculations I do when i add new page. Can you suggest, how to achieve this?

Comment: @OnkarSagar please create a minimal reproducible code sample for which the solution I provided would not be enough and add it to this question or ask a new one.

Comment: As for `addNewPage`, nothing prevents you from calling that method in my solution as well, it won't hurt

Comment: I have some doubts related to same thread : I need to add 2 tables on 2 parallel columns starting from page 1, and both tables have content more than a single page. Table1 runs on left half of page and table2 runs on right half. I started rendering table 1 and it overflows. Now before proceeding to next page, I want to start rendering table 2 (adding new page makes previous page inaccessible). Is it possible to process `document.add(table1)` and `document.add(table2)` simultaneously? Can we save state of document renderer for one table while we render other table?

Comment: @OnkarSagar just do it in two runs, it will be the simplest solution in your case

Comment: What i have understood from 'two runs' is that to call ```document.add(table1)``` and then call ```document.add(table2)```. but that will result in rendering table1 and then after completing table1 after some pages (say 3 pages), table2 will start from page 4. Can you explain more about 'two runs' and how to approach?